# Testing serverside part of program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, networking

I (will) have a program divided into client and server part, both being standalone programs.
they will communicate using Sockets (probably, or by some other Java networking method)

However, uploading a jar to a server and runing it there every single time I want to try something out seems painful especially since I can't see it's console.

Is there a system within Eclipse that would help me test the two standalone programs that would have to communicate as a client and a server? I'd have to be able to run both programs, see their console output and be able to debug them.

I have heard of Apache Tomcat, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for...

Comment: How will your server program be packaged? As a simple JAR, or as a WAR file, or...?

Comment: If it's just going to eventually be packaged as a JAR, you can just right-click the Main class in Eclipse, then select `Debug As -> Java application`. Eclipse will automatically create a Run Configuration, which you can later customize with startup arguments, etc.

Comment: You can run the server and client parts on your local, from eclipse.  If you are building a webapp you will need tomcat or some such, though there are many approaches and techniques to all of this.  If you're just using sockets, then you don't need anything special for dev.

Comment: So I'd just create two separate projects and run them at the same time?